# how to add html code to laravel controller?

Tags: html, laravel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glYdK.png)

I havee been tried using like this <a href="('.test->$id') >Button, but it doesn`t work.
The question is how to include 'route' on html code in a laravel controller.

Comment: "It doesn't work" sounds pretty broad, what does tht mean? Can you share the code you are using, and the errors you are facing to the question in readable form?

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not a best practice to write html in controller and it should be done in a blade file, you can use concatenation to use `route()` method within a string like below code:

```
return '<a href="'.route('test',$id).'">Button</a>';
```